# Why is the minimal value after applying cv2.normalize not exactly zero?

Tags: opencv, math, precision, numeric, normalize

I have a 2-D array with floating points. and I want to normalize it between 0-255 in python. I applied the opencv normalization like this:

```
result = cv2.normalize(my_array, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```

But result.min() is -5.9604645e-07. I know my data type is float and -5.9604645e-07 a very small value, but why isn't the result minimal value 0 or 0.0?

My opencv version is 4.7.0.

Comment: Please provide sample input that reproduces this behaviour, and state the version of OpenCV this happens with.

Comment: It must be a problem with the floating_point epsilon. Try using numpy.isclose function and it will make your minimum value turning to 0. Depending on your data, cv.normalize will act differently.